# Excel imports the HTML table incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, import

Some years I use a Linux script to create a HTML table with some statistic data. If the HTML document is given an extension .XLS, it could be directly opened (imported) with MS-Excel. As my statistic files grow by the time, and now it can hold more than half a million rows, the tables cannot be opened with elder MS-Excel. I tested the newer version MS-Excel 2013, and everything seemed to be fine. But Now I got a message from my customer, that the links (coming from HTML tag `<td><a href="./path/filename">fiename</a></td>`) are confusingly mixed up. In some tables, the header line is also broken, although it does not contain any link! In some end rows the links disappeared.

I checked the documents in text editor and everything seems to be OK. There were never problems with encoding, even the cells with math formula were correctly imported.

I tried to split a great table (>600000 rows) into a few smaller tables. Some of them seem to be OK some not. Even the same table was sometime imported correctly and sometime not.
I also checked the big table in HTML browsers (Firefox, IE, Edge, Opera) and there were no problem found, but it took extremely long time to load the table in. The LibreOffice Calc has also no problem.

If anybody can give me a hint, what may cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made lot of experiments, and I found two main reasons:

- UNIX line brake (LF) instead of MS-DOS/Windows (CRLF) causes Excel buffer overflow and consequent mismatch
- the used Excel version (2013) misinterprets links on imported rows beyond 65533

I add CR before end of each line with `sed`, and split table into smaller peaces <65000 lines.

To join the splited tables again, it shoud be converted into
a XML workbook of the excel spreadsheet format, which can content more worksheets.